# How to integrate Apple Pay with Knet PG?

Tags: angular, .net-core, payment

I am trying to integrate Apple Pay with Knet Payment Gateway but I am unable to find an extensive and elaborate document with the guide and the steps to be performed.
Apple Pay on the Web can be implemented and tested on compatible devices but using that data to authorize a payment using the Knet PG using an ASP.Net Core project is proving difficult.

I have gotten the Apple Pay session and window to open on a compatible Apple device amd have added test card data, but cannot find documentation as to how to integrate it with Knet PG using .NET Core.